# Creating and printing linked list from user input C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        node * next;
    };

    node * head;
    node * n;
    node * temp;
    node * q;
    int number;

    cout << "Enter numbers";
    cin >> number;
        n = new node;
        n->data = number; 
        head = n;
        temp = n; 
    while (cin >> number)
    {
        while (number != -500)
        {
            n = new node;
            n->data = number;
            temp->next = n;
            temp = n;

        }
    }


    while (head != NULL)
    {
        cout << head->data;
        head = head->next; 

    }
}
```

I don't understand why this would not work. The program creates a new node then sets whatever the user entered equivalent to the variable data of that new node then it makes head and temp point to the new node. Then it gets the users second input and compares it to -500 and if it evaluates as true it creates a new node puts the data of the second input into the variable data then it links the first node and second node together then it makes temp point to the second node. If the condition of the 2nd while loop is false it goes to the third which is where it is suppose to print the list.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I have already ran it through the debugger step by step. It gets the input but it is not doing anything with it. It breaks after the third input even if it is not equal -500.

Comment: `while (number != -500)` loops forever if `number` does not change in the loop body.

Comment: Change `while (number != -500)` to `if (number != -500)`.

Comment: @TenealaSpencer You'll need to learn how to use the debugger in a more proficient way.

Comment: Actually I realized the second while loop should be an if statement.

Comment: `new node` will not necessarily make the `next` field `NULL`. So the very first new node should make `next NULL`..

Answer (score 0):

Who sets the last node's next to NULL?

At n = new node; n->next is not NULL but undefined, in Debug versions usually it is 0xcccccccc or something similar value to make it visible that it is not initialized. If you try to dereference it, you will get an access violation.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (cin >> number) { // this loop is endless, because you can always read the user input data (unless some exception happen)
    while (number != -500)
    {
        n = new node; // you already have data allocated. no need to allocate it once more
        n->data = number;
        temp->next = n;
        temp = n;
// as was already mentioned: set n->next to NULL
    } }
```

if you want to break after you checked that the number is not -500, then you can do the following instead:

```
   while (cin >> number) {
    if (number != -500) { ...; // do your stuff
     break;
    }
   }
```

And, by the way, you have a memory leak. If you use flat C pointers then consider `delete` operator to clear your memory. For that purpose, you need to know where your list starts(basically, head) and iterate through a whole list invoking `delete node`.

Please, also consider, that it is a bad code style to write something like:

> while (cin >> number)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this-
This code makes a linked list on user input and printlinkedlist (function) print the linked list created.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    struct node 
    {
      int data;
      node* next;
    };
    void printlinkedlist(node* node)
    {
      int c=0; //taken just for good looking output
      while(node!=NULL)
      {
        if(c>0)
        {
          cout<<"->"<<node->data;
          node = node->next;
        }
        else
        {
          cout<<node->data;
          node = node->next;
          c++;
        }
      }
    }
    int main() {
      int n;
      cout<<"Enter no. of nodes=";
      cin>>n; //User enters number of nodes he want.
      int num,c=0; //initialized c for setting head with second node..
      node* head = new node; //initialized head node
      node * temp = new node; //initialized temp node 
      cin>>num;
      head->data=num;
      for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
      {
        if(c==0)
        {
          cin>>num;
          temp->data=num;
          head->next=temp; //head point to second node i.e. temp
          c++;
        }
        else
        {
          cin>>num;
          node * temp1 = new node; //initialize other temp node for every value 
          temp1->data=num;
          temp->next=temp1; //point to temp1 to temp 
          temp=temp1; //set temp as temp1 
        }
      }
      printlinkedlist(head); 
    }
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class node{
public:
int data;
node* next;
};

// a function to create linked list passing pointer to pinter
void create_list(node**head)
{
int num;//num is the data
    cin>>num ;

  node*new_node=new node();//
  new_node->data=num;
  new_node->next=NULL;
node*temp;
  if(*head==NULL)
 {
      *head=temp=new_node;
  }
  else{
      temp->next=new_node;
      temp=new_node;
  }
  
  }
  void print_list(node* head)
  {
if(head == NULL)
{
    cout<<"empty list"<<endl;
}
node *ptr = NULL;
ptr=head;
cout<<"data in the list: "<<endl;
while(ptr!=0)
{
    
    
        cout<<ptr->data<<endl;
        ptr=ptr->next;
    
   
}
}


int main()
{
int n,i; //
cout<<"enter the number of nodes:"<<endl;
cin>>n;
cout<<"enter data as num:"<<endl;
node* head=NULL; 
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
create_list(&head);//passing the address of head
}



print_list(head);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).